# Same SOCKET id when accept on linux?

Tags: c++, linux, intercept, ld-preload

I wrote LD_PRELOAD which intercepts accept() function. I have a problem because sometimes accept function gives me the same file descriptor. I load this preload only for one process

My code:

```
int accept(int sockfd, struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t *addrlen)
{
 int fd;
 fd = (*realAccept)(sockfd, addr, addrlen);
 if(fd >= 0)
 {
  printf("file descriptor: %d\n", fd);
  ...
  return fd;
 }
}

int close(int fd)
{
 printf("close decriptor: %d\n", fd);
 return (*realClose)(fd);
}
```

Output is:

> file descriptor: 213
>
> file descriptor: 213 <-- why?
>
> ...
>
> close decriptor: 213

Why accept function returns the same file descriptor?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you can rig the accept function to print some other information after the connection was accepted, e.g. the pid of the process, and the output from `lsof -p %u` for that pid. A `system` call might be able to achieve the latter.

Comment: i load this preload only to one process

Comment: Are you sure the process is not calling `fork()`?

Comment: Still, lsof might yield information as to whether these are two different connections, and whether the first one is still open under some other fd.

Answer (score 0):

I'd bet that this is an error due to the buffering of `stdout`. Maybe there are some other threads using it...  That added to the fact that you did not include an ending `\n` can result in duplicated lines in the output.

If you want to be sure, add the `\n` at the end of the string and an `fflush(stdout)` after every call to `printf()`.

Comment: Can you try printing a global variable and increment it every time, just to be sure that you are being called twice?: `printf("file descriptor: %d   %d\n", fd, global++);`